# Firebase cloud function completing before all functions have run

Tags: javascript, firebase, async-await, google-cloud-functions

I'm trying to call the following function. Have tried await and Promise.all() but I'm still seeing my firebase functions execution complete before the get request returns. The code eventually completes but due to how firebase works it takes 2 or 3 minutes because firebase runs it as some kind of background task.

I've placed logging on every line of the executing function. When it gets to the line which calls (request.get), firebase stops and exits. I've also tried adding await in here but the code doesn't block and wait.

```
function fetchUserLogoBase64(userId) {
  return new Promise(async function(resolve, reject) {
    const userSettings = await getDocument("user-settings", userId);
    const downloadUrl = userSettings.company.logoDownloadUrl;

    if (!downloadUrl) return null;

    request.get(downloadUrl, function(error, response, body) {
      if (!error && response.statusCode === 200) {
        data =
          "data:" +
          response.headers["content-type"] +
          ";base64," +
          new Buffer(body).toString("base64");
        resolve(data);
      }
      reject(error);
    });
  });
}
```

Comment: There's not enough information here to know what's going on.  I'll note that you're unnecessarily creating a new promise object - that's not required.  Please edit the question to provide an MCVE: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: @DougStevenson `request.get()` as used here doesn't return a promise, which is probably why OP explicitly created their own promise.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen Oh, well, there is a version of `request` that returns a promise. Surprisingly, it's called `request-promise`.

Comment: Yup, that's an add-on package. Although most folks switch over to using `fetch` these days.

Answer (score 0):

You're mixing promises with `async` / `await`, which makes it even harder to follow what is happening then using either one. I recommend picking either promises or `async` / `await` and using only that.

With pure promises, this code would look like:

```
function fetchUserLogoBase64(userId) {
  return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
    getDocument("user-settings", userId).then(function(userSettings) {
      const downloadUrl = userSettings.company.logoDownloadUrl;

      if (!downloadUrl) resolve();

      request.get(downloadUrl, function(error, response, body) {
        if (!error && response.statusCode === 200) {
          data =
            "data:" +
            response.headers["content-type"] +
            ";base64," +
            new Buffer(body).toString("base64");
          resolve(data);
        }
        reject(error);
      });
    });
  });
}
```